# Prove: |= ∀xϕ→ψ ↔ ∃x(ϕ→ψ), with x not belonging to FV (ψ)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers

|= (∀xϕ→ψ) ↔ (∃x(ϕ→ψ)), with x not belonging to FV(ψ) (Free Variable).

I have been struggling with this exercise for a while. I have to prove this formula using either the valuations or [as shown in this example in Van Dalen's "Logic and Structure"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJgAx.jpg) (I do not know the name of this method) with a more verbal(?) approach if you will.

[Lemma which is referenced in the book just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ35b.png)

I know that I have to reach, at some point during the demonstration that ∀x(ϕ→ψ), but I
don't understand how to translate it (from one language to the other and back to the formula) correctly in order to do that.

Not sure if this is correct but I got up to that point and I'm not sure how I continue:

Note: I'm using a' to refer to the element from the language and a to refer to the interpretation of a' in that language.

- Let FV( (∀xϕ→ψ) ↔ (∃x(ϕ→ψ)) ) = {z1, ..., zk}.
- We must prove that for all structure A with an appropriate type:

  A |= ∀z1,...zk( (∀xϕ→ψ)(x, z1,...,zk) ↔ (∃x(ϕ→ψ))(x,z1,...zk) )
- So we have to show that:

  A |= (∀xϕ→ψ)(x, a'1,...,a'k) ↔ (∃x(ϕ→ψ))(x,a'1,...a'k) for arbitrary a'1,..., a'k that belongs to |A|
- A |= (∀xϕ→ψ)(x, a'1, ..., a'k) ⇔
- A |= for all b that belongs to |A| ϕ(b, a'1, ..., a'k) implies A |= ψ(a'1,...,a'k) ⇔
- ...

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $\models (\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi))$, with $x \notin \mathrm{FV}(\psi)$.

As you may know, $\models (\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)) \iff \mathfrak{A} \models (\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi))$, for every $\mathfrak{A}$ of the appropriate type.

Hence, we may pick an arbitrary $\mathfrak{A}$ so as to demonstrate our property.

Now, by 2.4.5, $\mathfrak{A} \models (\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)) \iff \mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{A} \models  \exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$.

Hence, let us demonstrate the dual implication.

($\implies$) As $x \notin \mathrm{FV}(\psi)$, $\mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi \iff \mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ (I believe this is a previously shown result in the book, but if not it can be easily shown). From here on out you may easily deduce $\mathfrak{A} \models  \exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ either via derivation rules of natural deduction or, through 2.4.5, as $\mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \iff \mathfrak{A} \models \phi(\overline{a}) \rightarrow \psi(\overline{a})$, for every $a \in |\mathfrak{A}| \implies \mathfrak{A} \models \phi(\overline{a}) \rightarrow \psi(\overline{a})$, for some $a \in |\mathfrak{A}| \iff \mathfrak{A} \models  \exists x \ (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$.

($\impliedby$) We shall assume to be working with sentences so as to make matters easier, but in the case that $\mathrm{FV}(\psi), \mathrm{FV}(\phi) \setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$, just perform a previous quantifier closure and select arbitrary $z_1, \dots, z_k$ from $\mathrm{FV}(\psi) \cup \mathrm{FV}(\phi) \setminus \{x\}$. This implication could be easily obtained via natural deduction, but let us stick to semantics (and hence to 2.4.5).

As $x \notin \mathrm{FV}(\psi)$, there are two cases to consider: (i) $\mathfrak{A} \models \psi$; (ii) $\mathfrak{A} \not \models \psi$.

If (i), the desired result is immediate, as $\mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi \iff \mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \Rightarrow \mathfrak{A} \models \psi$ will be immediately true.

If (ii), we have then that there is some $a \in |\mathfrak{A}|$ such that $\mathfrak{A} \models \phi(\overline{a}) \rightarrow \psi$. As $\mathfrak{A} \not \models \psi$, such can only be if $\mathfrak{A} \not \models \phi(\overline{a})$. Hence, it can be easily shown that $\mathfrak{A} \not \models \forall x \ \phi(x)$ and thus $\mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \psi \iff \mathfrak{A} \models \forall x \ \phi \Rightarrow \mathfrak{A} \models \psi$ is vacuously true.

$\square$